# Max number of permutations of a dynamic field name across documents in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

Let's say my solr schema has 9 predefined fields and 1 dynamic field like this:

```
<dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
```

Also, for this question only a single "*_i" prefix will be used on each document so that the total count of fields on every solr document is always 10.  But what if the prefix which is used varies widely across the documents?  To give an example, what if I create a hundred million solr documents (again, each with only 10 total fields) and there was a million different prefixes used across them for that dynamic field.

This would be for solr 6.x and any solr searches would always be filtering on some of the other predefined fields (like a group_id field) plus the dynamic field.  Let's also assume that knowing which dynamic field to use in the solr search has been figured out.

What are the implications of that kind of set up?  Does solr care more about how many fields exist on each document vs the cardinality of the dynamic field names themselves across documents?

Comment: Are you going to sort on the dynamic fields? This is important as Solr will keep a cache for each field that you've sorted by, and this cache will be sized to the total number of documents in the index, and not to the number of documents in your result set. docValues can help mitigate this as well, iirc.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I might need to sort on the dynamic fields but I'm still in the process of determining what I will support.  I could potentially live without supporting that.

Comment: As long as the number of documents for each prefix will be low, you can perform the sorting client side in your controller / data interface. We had one field indicating if they had a certain prefix, so we could filter on that with `fq` (i.e. `fq=has_prefix:foo_bar`) and then sorted on the values of `foo_bar_i` in our data retrieval class. That gives one coherent cache for filtering, and you avoid the sort cache in Solr growing way too large.